# JavaScript select function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use JavaScript to copy text to clipboard. Here is what I've got so far

```
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('#copy');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.getElementById('toCopy');
  copyTextarea.focus();
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
    alert("Link copied!");
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Unable to copy!");
  }
});
```

I get the error that copyTextarea.select is not a function. Why is that? I'm 100% sure that JavaScript does have a select method.

Comment: Depends on your environment, What browser are you using and which version is it?

Comment: Here is the compatibility for it from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent#Browser_compatability

As Mr. Alien mentioned(deleted comment now?). If you're not in those environments, using flash is and has been the way to do it.

Comment: I'm using Chrome v49

Comment: [Works just fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/Lhfhzocv/).

Comment: You can try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange#Browser_compatibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure the element with id as "toCopy" is of type textarea